# How to represent an optimum area in the contour plot (filled.contour) by a specific color?

Tags: r, plot, colors

I am using `filled.contour` function to plot a contour map. I want to represent the area around an optimum value by a dark color and all other regions in light color.

```
library(gplots) 
a <- expand.grid(1:20, 1:20)
b <- matrix(a[, 1] + a[, 2], 20)
filled.contour(x = 1:20, y = 1:20, z = b,
               plot.axes = { axis(1); axis(2); points(10, 10) },
               col = colorpanel(10, "white", "grey10"))
```

I want to represent (10,10) coordinates by a dark grey color and all other regions by a light color. I have also tried `RColorBrewer` and `colorRampPalette` to vary the gradients, but it did not give the desired result. How can I vary the color gradients to accomplish my goal?

Regards,
Ashwani

Comment: You said you want the point (10,10) to be dark grey and everything else light. But then why use gradient colors. Can you be more specific about how you want the plot to look?

Comment: The code I posted is just an example. Please see the edited question. The idea is to highlight the optimum area. My optimum area in the above plot is around the coordinate (3.5e+07,30) and I want to highlight that specific area with grey color. I also have low and high values in the plot which I do not care for.  These low and high values would be represented by a light color. Hope this helps.

Comment: seems I cannot post images. Sorry for that. Let me try again with the toy example. Say my optimum area is around the coordinate (10,10). I want this specific area to be highlighted/filled with a dark color. I have low and high values represented by other regions, which I do not care. I want these high and low values to be represented by a light color.

Comment: Error. Cannot find `colorpanel`. It a real PITA when non-base packag functions are not loaded with library or require calls.

Comment: @BondedDust : install.packages(gplots), library(gplots)

Answer (score 1):

The filled contour is really two separate plots that are set up with `layout`, In your case, the x coordinates are shifted to the left and the region of interest can be highlighted with:

```
rect(7,9.5,8,10.5,col='red')
```

Your example is curiously similar to the example in `?filled.contour` that does pretty much does exactly what you ask. I'm left wondering if this is a question posed by a professor who wants to see whether his students actually read the help pages for the functions they are using.

```
a <- expand.grid(1:20, 1:20)
b <- matrix(a[,1] + a[,2], 20)
filled.contour(x = 1:20, y = 1:20, z = b,
               plot.axes = { axis(1); axis(2); points(10, 10) })
```